# Alter query using pre_get_posts() if meta_key is present

Tags: loop, pre-get-posts

I am trying to modify the number of posts per page for archive pages that contain category sticky posts (added by the [Category Sticky post plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/category-sticky-post/))

to do so I am using the `pre_get_posts`hook and have tried the following :

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_set_category_posts_per_page' );

function my_set_category_posts_per_page( $query ) {

  global $wp_the_query;

  if ( 'category_sticky_post' === $query->get( 'meta_key' ) && ! is_paged ) {

        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 8 );

  }

  return $query;
}
```

I `var_dump($query)` I do get `[meta_key] => category_sticky_post` in the `query_vars` but I can't sort out how to use it.

Another idea is to use something like this:

```
function my_set_category_posts_per_page( $query ) {

  $args = array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'category_sticky_post',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS'
        )
    );
    $meta_query = new WP_Meta_Query($args);

    if ( 'category_sticky_post' === $query->get('meta_query', $meta_query) && ! is_paged() ) {

       $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 8 );

    }
}
```

How would I alter the query only when the meta key is present for the posts in the current query?

Comment: Is the key/value `[meta_key] => category_sticky_post` nested under query_vars in the `$query` object?  I think your condition should look more like `'category_sticky_post' === $query->query_vars['meta_key']`

Comment: it is indeed. Thanks, I'll have to wait until tomorrow to test it. I think I did try that but I'm not sure now. It looks like it should work.

Comment: So when I `var_dump($query->query_vars['meta_key'])` I do get `category_sticky_post`but however the condition doesn't return true.

Comment: How about posting a dump of the entire `$query` object to Gist or Pastebin, etc?   Can't guarantee a solution but I'm happy to take a deeper look.

Comment: That would be great. I would love another pair of eyes on it. I'll do that tomorrow. Thanks :)

Comment: https://gist.github.com/mantismamita/fa2f5b1f381979c4dc18faba72b3cdce

Answer (score 0):

Based on data from your Gist, the following `pre_get_posts` condition should work to limit your posts per page.

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_set_category_posts_per_page' );

function my_set_category_posts_per_page() {
    global $wp_query;

    if ( 'category_sticky_post' === $wp_query->query_vars['meta_key'] ) {
      $wp_query->set( 'posts_per_page', 8 );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I won't have a chance to try it out until tomorrow but looks promising ;)

Comment: Afraid it work. I think it has to use `$wp_the_query` and pass in `$query`as a parameter. At least that's how I have it working elsewhere. Cheers for trying :)

Comment: nevermind that last comment. Turns out they are the same thing.